# The way $C^{k_1}$ and $C^{k_2}$ geometries are different.

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-geometry, differential-topology

I want to illustrate the point that $C^{k_2}$ regularity cares more about geometry than $C^{k_1}$ regularity when $k_1 > k_2$. Do you have any example of two $C^1$-submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (or $\mathbb{R^2}$) $M_1$ and $M_2$ so that $M_1$ is homeomorphic to $M_2$, both are $C^1$ submanifolds but they are not $C^1$ diffeomorphic? (or $C^2, C^3, ...$ submanifolds if it helps to give an easier example.)

---

Update: I think I've got an idea. Suppose you have the graph of the function $(x^2 + 1)\sin x$ as $M_2$ and the $x$-axis as $M_1$ both as submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^2$. I think they can't be $C^1$ diffeomorphic since if there is a diffeomorphism $\phi: M_1 \longrightarrow M_2$, it should have infinite $C^1$-norm. (Like what happens to $x \longmapsto x^2$ that prevents it to be a $C^1$-diffeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}$ and the graph of $|x|$. (Of course $\text{graph}(x\mapsto |x|)$ is not a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$. But the idea seems useful.) My idea was to force the same phenomena by defining $M_2$ so that it's graph has arbitrary big slopes. But am I correct about $\|\phi\|_{C^1} = \infty$? (A reason I thought of an example with non-compact shapes is the classification theorems we have for nice compact manifolds).

Comment: As far as I remember, in dimension $\leq 3$, we have that topological, $C^k$, PL and smooth manifold structures 
 all coincide. And therefore you won't find a counterexample in such a small dimension. I'm not sure what you mean in your second part: graphs of $x^2$ and $|x|$ are diffeomorphic, given appropriate smooth structures.

Comment: For a higher dimensional example have a look at [small exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_R4#Small_exotic_R4s) which is homeomorphic to the standard $\mathbb{R}^4$, it is a submanifold of it (in fact an open subset), but they are not diffeomorphic.

Comment: @freakish Thanks for your comment. It was very interesting to know the restrictions in small dimensions. I wasn't aware of that. For the second part, this is why I am forcing the manifolds to inherit the smooth structure of their Euclidean space and therefore fail to be diffeomorphic.

Comment: What is your definition of submanifold then? Because the graph of $|x|$ does not sound like a submanifold with differential structure inherited from $\mathbb{R}^2$. Which I'm not even sure what it means.

Comment: @freakish You're absolutely correct. I think I might have been a little misleading. The point was that I wanted to make use of the fact that the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ blows up. In the other example, $\text{graph} \Big(x \mapsto (x^2 + 1) \sin x \Big)$ is a submanifold though. Do you think the argument I gave is fine there?

Comment: The graph of any $C^k$ function indeed is a $C^k$ submanifold. However $\sqrt{x}$ does not really give you anything. Just because some function is not differentiable doesn't imply that there is no diffeomorphism. And as I said: you won't find an example in such a low dimension. I'm not really good at exotic geometry, so I can't help you beyond that, sorry.

Comment: @freakish Thanks for your help. Yes, I'm well aware that when a single function fails to be a diffeomorphism it doesn't mean that all functions fail. I believe I was trying to force the same thing that failed $x \mapsto x^2$ for all functions on my example, namely infinite $C^1$-norm. That being said, if you're statement is correct, there should be an error in my example?